# How to switch off my accessibility service app from the same app android?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am working an accessibility service app . All I want is to switch it off from a button click of the same app. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the device is rooted, i doubt this is possible.

Anyways, you can open up the accessibility service page so that the user can turn it On/OFF.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```